# cross-compatibility - box-shadow with multiple line span

Tags: html, css

I have an element that uses box-shadow to give it a background that follows the length of an inline element and, more importantly, stays consistent when you shrink the window and the text spills into a new line.

http://jsfiddle.net/ric0c/dgersydv/

```
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 0 0px 0px #7E8573, -10px 0 0 #7E8573;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 0 0px 0px #7E8573, -10px 0 0 #7E8573;
  box-shadow: 4px 0 0px 0px #7E8573, -10px 0 0 #7E8573;
  background: #7E8573;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
  margin: 18px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: pre-line;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
```

Now this works correctly on Chrome and Safari but I'm getting inconsistencies on Firefox.  If use `white-space: pre-line;` I lose the "padding" on the left and right sides.  If use `white-space: pre-wrap;` the text no longer stays in line with the line above when it spills over.

Any thoughts on how to get this consistent on all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want `white-space`. It causes problems because you have line breaks inside the `h2`. Just remove it, or remove the line breaks.

And then, the difference between Firefox and Chrome is that Chrome behaves like if you used [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break)`: clone`, but the initial value should be `slice`.

So just add

```css
h2 {
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```css
h2 {
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 0 0px 0px #7E8573, -10px 0 0 #7E8573;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 0 0px 0px #7E8573, -10px 0 0 #7E8573;
  box-shadow: 4px 0 0px 0px #7E8573, -10px 0 0 #7E8573;
  background: #7E8573;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
  margin: 18px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus luctus.
</h2>
```